# How to resolve vagrant mount issue?

Tags: macos, vagrant, mount

Vagrant up is not working properly after restarting the machine. Before restart, it was working fine. It is hang up after `"default: Mounting NFS shared folders"` and throwing an error like `"mount.nfs: Connection timed out"`.

I have checked the exports file and restore with blank data.

```
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp,rw,actimeo=2 192.168.200.1:/Users/USERNAME/vagrant/ol7/vagabond7 /var/nfs//Users/USERNAME/vagrant/ol7/vagabond7
```

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

> mount.nfs: Connection timed out